# Less mixin, extract colors from array and on hover, add darken to that array

Tags: arrays, less, less-mixins

Is it possible to darken an array with colors? Like this:

```
@array: @color1 @color2 @color3 @color4
.color-mix(@i) when (@i > 0) {
    .myClass {
        li:nth-child(@{i}) {
            .background-color(extract(@array, @i));
            &:hover {
              // THIS IS NOT WORKING, IS THERE A RIGHT APPROACH FOR THIS?
                .background-color(extract(darken(@array, 5.5%, @i)));
            }
        }
    .color-mix(@i - 1);
    }
}
// Iterate
.color-mix(4);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, yes, you can achieve that. Below is how you do it. Your code was almost correct except that instead of trying to darken the extracted value, it was trying to extract a darkened value (which is not possible).

```css
@array: #fff #00f #ff0 #f00;

.color-mix(@i) when (@i > 0) {
  .myClass {
    li:nth-child(@{i}) {
      .background-color(extract(@array, @i));
      &:hover {
        .background-color(darken(extract(@array, @i), 5.5%));
      }
    }
  }
    .color-mix(@i - 1); /* I have moved it because I think it was wrongly placed */
}
// Iterate
.color-mix(4);
```

---

One improvement that I would suggest to your code is to move the `:hover` selector also within the `.background-color` mixin like below. This makes it a bit more easier to read as there is no wrapping of a function call within another function and so on.

```css
@array: #fff #00f #ff0 #f00;

.color-mix(@i) when (@i > 0) {
  .myClass {
    li:nth-child(@{i}) {
      .background-color(extract(@array, @i));
    }
  }
    .color-mix(@i - 1);
}
// Iterate
.color-mix(4);

.background-color(@color){
  &{
    background-color: @color;
    &:hover{
      background-color: darken(@color, 5.5%);
    }
  }
}
```

---

Even better would be this - just avoid the mixin if you can :)

```css
@array: #fff #00f #ff0 #f00;

.color-mix(@i) when (@i > 0) {
  .myClass {
    li:nth-child(@{i}) {
      @color: extract(@array, @i);
      background-color: @color;
      &:hover{
        background-color: darken(@color, 5.5%);
      }
    }
  }
    .color-mix(@i - 1);
}
// Iterate
.color-mix(4);
```

Comment: oh! So I only did it wrong order kind of. Well, thanks!

Comment: Yes @Flirt and I have also added another sample. Take a look and it might help you because it looks more understandable and cleaner (instead of wrapping a function within a function and so on..) :)